# How do I set the color of a line chart in shiny?

Tags: r, plotly

I succesfully changed the color of my bar chart by using this command:

```
marker = list(color = 'rgb(214, 39, 40)'))
```

But when I do this for a line chart, it only changes the color of the  dots instead of the whole line. How can I do that?

Comment: This has to do with `plotly`, not `shiny`, right ?

Comment: I think you should just add `line = list(color = xxx)`.

Comment: What are you using to build your visualizations? ggplot? plotly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using plotly indeed and that is the correct way to do it thanks!